How to assign an argument with a dynamic value in K8s
Simple and short, in a Deployment yaml file, I need to pass the unique name of the pod as an argument to the executing process in the pod.
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ABC
    image: any_unknown_image
    env:
    - name: NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.uid
    args: 
    - "name"
    - "${NAME}" # <-- How to pass NAME to this one??

How can I do this?
Please do not suggest workarounds:

The image is any image and we cannot configure how it reads arguments.
We cannot create a yaml template and update it!
The value MUST be dynamically passed only and only by Kubernetes and not any other mechanism.


Just found the answer, and will add for future reference here only:
env:
- name: MESSAGE
  value: "hello world"
command: ["/bin/echo"]
args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]

